# Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

currently I have an Html form with javascript validation. Currently the errors are showing in a popup by using the alert command.... how I can display error messages next to the text boxes please? Below is my current code:

```
 if (document.gfiDownloadForm.txtFirstName.value == '') {
  alert('Please fill in all required fields');
  return false;
 }

 var filter = /^([a-zA-Z '-]+)$/i
 if (filter.test(document.gfiDownloadForm.txtFirstName.value) == false) {
  alert('Please enter a valid First name');
  return false;
 }

 var filter = /^([a-zA-Z '-]+)$/i
 if (filter.test(document.gfiDownloadForm.txtLastName.value) == false) {
  alert('Please enter a valid Last name');
  return false;
 }


 if (document.gfiDownloadForm.txtCompany.value == '') {
  alert('Please enter a Company name');
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: Make sure to also have server side validation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add additional form elements (likely a span since they're inline, rather than a div which is a block element) to hold the error messages next to your input form elements and give it an id so that you can reference it in your javascript. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" /><span id="firstNameError"></span>
```

Then in your Javascript code you'd set the innerHTML of that form element to your error message if it doesn't validate, or to an empty string '' if it does validate, like so:

```
if (filter.test(document.gfiDownloadForm.txtFirstName.value) == false) {
    document.getElementById("firstNameError").innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid First name.';
    return false;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("firstNameError").innerHTML = '';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're returning `false` in both cases; mistake? Moreover, when using DOM level 2 event binding, you should use the corresponding functions/properties of the Event interface to stop default behaviour.

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake on my part. Since the return value didn't seem to be used in the sample code in the question, I didn't pay too much attention to it when copying it over to my own. Edited the answer to return true if it validates correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `<div>` or `<span>` next to the input field, and instead of an `alert` statement simply set the content of the `<div>` to the appropriate error message.

e.g.

```
if (document.gfiDownloadForm.txtCompany.value == '') {
  document.getElementById('company_error').innerHTML = 'Please enter a company name';
  return false;
}
```